# Laptop won't start, BSOD. Setting BIOS defaults makes no difference

Tags: laptop, bios, bsod, reboot

I get a BSOD nearly every time I turn on the laptop.

Sometime Windows displays an error and asks whether to start normally or in safe mode etc.
I tried starting it in every mode. It would start Windows for a bit then it would restart by itself. Then either showing the Windows error again or BSOD.

I set all BIOS settings to their default. Now after powering on the computer switches off after a fews seconds. It doesn't get a chance to display anything on screen.

Opened the laptop. made sure everything is connected the way it was and it is the same.

My laptop is Dell inspiron N5010 with Windows 7 (not under warranty).

What could be going on, what can I try?

Comment: A problem like this normally indicates the CPU is no longer working.  Since you have a laptop and its not under warranty your options are very limited, since a latop CPU, cannot be replaced by you.

Comment: Do you actually get a [BSOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death) or does it just shut down? Is the machine hot?

Comment: upload the dmp files from C:\Windows\Minidump

Comment: I dont get a BSOD anymore, it just gets in a loop of turning on and off indefinitely. It does not get hot. I will try to get the dump files

Answer (score 0):

If the computer switches off before booting the OS, it's a hardware problem. From the symptoms, it could be anything: bad RAM, bad CPU, loose connections, bad power supply...

The computer will have to be repaired. If you cannot do it yourself, and it's not under warranty, the only options I see are:

- Take it to a shop that will repair it. This may or may not be (too) expensive; try to get a quote or set a price limit for the repair.
- Sell it as defective (online auction site, local yard sale), and get a new one.